# How to display multiple inputs on the same page in a container

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to display details inputted into the form in the div on the same page, when the submit button is clicked, it doesn't display.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function checkinput(){
    var a,b,c,d;
     a = document.getElementById("fname").value;
     b = document.getElementById("lname").value;
     c = document.getElementById("address").value;
     d = document.getElementById("email").value;
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = a + b + c + d ;
}

</script>
```

```
<form id = "myform" onsubmit ="return false" >
       <p>Firstname : <input type="text" name="Firstname" id="fname" value=""></p>
       <p>Last name  : <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname" value=""></p>
       <p>Address    : <input type="text" name="Address" id = "address" value=""></p>
       <p>Email     :  <input type="email" name="Email" id = "email" value=""></p>
       <button onclick = "check()">submit</button>

</form>

<div id="output" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;border: 1px solid black">

</div>
```

I expect details inputted in the form to display in the div element below.

Comment: Your onclick event handler calls a function named `check` but you only define a function named `checkinput`

Comment: `check()` and `checkinput()` is not the same thing ?

Comment: @adeneo `onsubmit ="return false"`

Comment: @j08691 This is simpler .... As a `button`'s type defaults to _submit_, add `type='button'` to it to avoid form being submitted

Comment: @LGSon thanks, I'm well aware of how to stop a form from submitting. I was just noting to adeneo that the OP did attempt to stop the form from submitting

Comment: @j08691 Am sure you both are :) ... just wanted to post it

Comment: Thanks changing checkinput() to check() resolved this, please how do i display the results on a separate line

Comment: @LGSon Sorry, just re-read my comment and it looks like it could be read with some attitude. None intended

Comment: document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = a + "<br/>" +  b + "<br/>" +  c + "<br/>" + d;

Comment: @j08691 None taken :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the method you try to call when button is clicked.
`<button onclick="checkinput()">submit</button>`

To put every part on its own line, add the "
" between them

```js
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
a + "<br/>" +  b + "<br/>" +  c + "<br/>" + d;
```

#### UPD

you can set the default type of the button to the "button" as it was recommended above and in this case, you don't need to handle the "onsubmit" event for the form

```html
<form id="myform">
    <p>Firstname : <input type="text" name="Firstname" id="fname" value=""></p>
    <p>Last name : <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname" value=""></p>
    <p>Address : <input type="text" name="Address" id="address" value=""></p>
    <p>Email : <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" value=""></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="checkinput()">submit</button>
</form>
```

After that, you can use different js functions depending on your purposes

```
// Strait forward - just get names from the array and use the values 
// in any way you like
    function checkinput1() {
        let html = "";
        for(let name of ["fname", "lname", "address", "email"]) {
            html += document.getElementById(name).value + "<br/>";
        }
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
    }

// If you need just to concatenate values
    function checkinput2() {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `${document.getElementById('fname').value}
        <br/>${document.getElementById('lname').value}
        <br/>${document.getElementById('address').value}
        <br/>${document.getElementById('email').value}`;
    }

// When you want to get all values from the form inputs and don't 
// care about their real names. You can also skip the empty values, so
// no empty lines will be added to the result
    function checkinput3(){
        let values = [];
        for(let elem of document.querySelectorAll('#myform input')){
            if(elem.value) values.push(elem.value);
        }
        document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = values.join('<br/>');
    }
```

Comment: Based on the main comments I made the assumption OP missed to prevent the form from submitting...just now noticed they already did.

Comment: The code there looks so strange - so it's not a surprise that anyone can miss this detail :-)
No offense taken!

Comment: Still, that is considered a _typo_, and such question we don't answer, we use the built-in "vote/flag to close as a typo"

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @AlexeyZelenin please can you assist with a more readable way of writing the code and getting the same result? Thanks